# How to combine several querysets by key in common?

Tags: python, django, performance, postgresql, django-queryset

I have several querysets which have to be combined effectively. All querysets have common field `key` and I want to concatenate by its value query results. E.g:

```
some_query = SomeObject.objects.values('key').annotate(sum_0=Sum('some_value_field'))
other_query = OtherObject.objects.values('key', 'other_field').annotate(sum_1=Sum('some_other_value_field'))
```

What I have:

```
[{'key': 1, 'sum_0': 10}, {'key': 2, 'sum_0': 20}, ...]
[{'key': 1, 'sum_1': 1000}, {'key': 2, 'sum_1': 200}, ...]
```

What I want:

```
[{'key': 1, 'sum_0': 10, 'sum_1': 100}, {'key': 2, 'sum_0': 20, 'sum_1': 200}, ...]
```

I am using this method to combine dicts:

```
d = defaultdict(dict)
for item in [some_query, other_query]:
    for elem in item:
        d[elem['key']].update(elem)
combined = d.values()
```

Is there more effective way to accomplish that other than dictionary merge by iterating through every queryset or maybe there is a way to combine those querysets by `key` into one result in query itself?

Comment: AFAIK you can't combien data from distinct tables using Django ORM/pure SQL.

Comment: @MaximeLorant thanks for answer, did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the annotations to perform only one db operation:

```
SomeObject.objects.values('key', 'other_field').annotate(sum_0=Sum('some_value_field'), sum_1=Sum('some_other_field'))
```

Comment: That is not what I want. I want to map to query results by one key in common. Will edit question in a second.

Comment: I have changed the description as if it would be two different queries but has the same key field. I map now with iterating through those dictionaries , but I would like to make something more fancy/effective (maybe on db side).

Comment: Ah I see. If there is not relation between the objects, I don't think its possible.

Answer (score 0):

itertools.chain is my preferred way, but annotations can work.

Comment: hmm, I need not only add all querysets to one list but also to combine dicts by keys. I updated method which is used now.